# Graph series of parabolas

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image: Series of parabolas]

Having trouble writing the right code for this graph
If anyone could help I'll be thankful.

y=ax^2
α={-2.4,-2.1,...2,4}

Answer (score 5):

Welcome! You can create your own `cycle list` for the alternating pattern of line styles, and use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to loop over the plots to obtain

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{pft}{
    cyan,solid\\
    red,dashed\\
}   
\begin{axis}[xmin=-7,xmax=7,ymin=-25,ymax=25,
    xtick={-6,-4,...,6},ytick={-20,0,20},grid=major,
    ylabel={$y$},xlabel={$x$},
    cycle list name=pft]
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2.4,-2.1,...,2.4}{
 \addplot+[no marks,domain=-7:7,smooth]{#1*x*x};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]