# What is the parable expression for this?

Tags: pgfplots

Im having some trouble finding out the expression for this parable. This is what I've got. What Am I missing?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$x(t)$,xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-2,ymax=2,grid=major,grid style={solid}]
\addplot[line width=1pt,smooth, a=-2.4] expression{ax^2};
\addplot[domain=-5:5,blue,samples=125,line width=1pt] expression{ax^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It is `<coefficient>*x*x` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543904/194703), which produces the plot (more or less) exactly.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat we should contact the instructor of the course and ask that at least he could change the problem every other year... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano So you are asking for a `problem cycle list`, right? ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ;-)